# EF Core CreateDateTime could not be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to run a linq to entities query in EF Core 6, but I'm receiving an exception saying that System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.CreateDateTime could not be translated.

My goal is to filter a collection by initial and final month and year.

Im trying that:

```
var initialDate = new DateTime(request.InitialYear, request.InitialMonth, 1);
var finalDate = new DateTime(request.FinalYear,request.FinalMonth, 1);

query = query.where(q => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(q.Year,q.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0) >= initialDate && System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(q.Year,q.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0) <= finalDate);
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: Side note: you should probably not use functions on columns in the `Where` clause anyway, as it can't use indexes. Instead put the function on the parameter `query.Where(q => (q.Year == request.InitialYear && q.Month >= request.InitialMonth || q.Year > request.InitialYear) && (q.Year == request.FinalYear && q.Month <= request.FinalMonth || q.Year < request.FinalYear));` alternatively redesign the original table to use a proper date column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Data.Entity` is not part of Entity Framework Core, so its classes and methods may not be translated by EF. I did a quick search and found `EF.Functions.DateFromParts` in package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`. It means that query translation heavily depends on database provider. You have not specified one in your question.

Usage:

`EF.Functions.DateFromParts(q.Year, q.Month, 1) >= initialDate`

Comment: Im using SqlServer provider, EF.Functions.DateFromParts works for me, thank you very much.